# Angular 2 & Ionic 2: Access Swiper slide data-attribute

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

My Angular 2/Ionic 2 template looks like this:

```
<ion-slides #setSlider [options]="setSliderOptions" (ionDidChange)="onSetSlideChanged()">
    <ion-slide [attr.data-timer]="exercise.sets[setNumber].pause">
        {{timer}}
    </ion-slide>
    ...
</ion-slides>
```

Now i want to access the active slide `<ion-slide>` data attribute.

`let setSliderIndex = this.setSlider.getActiveIndex();` gives me the active index, but is there a way to get the data attribute?

Comment: *Where* do you want to access the data? Don't you already have it in the component?

Comment: You could get the nativeElement from the slides reference and then look up the element that is active and get the attribute from that. But why all of this?